# Create unique form fields based on database query in Symfony 1.4/Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4, dynamic, doctrine-1.2

I have this wild project happening at work, and we happen to use Symfony 1.4 so I was hoping, ideally, to keep this project within the framework's capabilities as much as possible. Unfortunately, despite quite a bit of research and searching, I haven't yet found a way to generate sfWidgetForm elements based on queries to the database.

I'll outline what the purpose of this is by explaining the flow of the project.

1. The user submits a form which contains *most* of the data our advertisers need.
2. Based on this data, rows from a database can be called. Perhaps this form was filled, and in it, the user claims to be interested in gardening. Based on that relevance this will yield a row (or several rows, but whatever) of form fields related to gardening.
3. Here in lies the important part. This gardening related content is essentially an outline of form fields required to a complete a submission for someone who is interested in gardening. We will get form element types, names, labels, requirement status, enablement status, etc. Based on the ids of these elements, we can see if any of them are dependent on each other from another table. If that's the case, they are treated with javascript. That's another story.
4. At this point, I can either create forms using custom built components in Symfony (Which would be alright). These would output forms which worked fine, but they wouldn't be supported by sfValidator widgets, which is unfortunate. What I'd like to do is *somehow* tell some magical form class to build a form based on X criterion, widgets and validators all.
5. Once the form is complete and outputted, the user fills in the remaining fields, the second form gets validated and the whole whack of data from both forms is sent to the advertiser.

What I'm most interested in here is data on dynamically building forms within Symfony. I can build using a component easily, but I don't really want to. Especially since I plan to quit soon, and keeping something within the framework would be ideal for my team mates.

Thanks for any ideas! This is a pretty exciting project, despite being boring from the outside - I've never dynamically generated forms before, let alone within Symfony. Should be cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functioning example of how I solved this problem can be found here: http://pastebin.com/NrJeADAk

It works well. If your database describe your forms properly and consistently, you can even create new forms by submitting their descriptions via a form. I've done this for my team at work, and with very heavy validation on the fields, so far they haven't managed to create a single form that causes issues. I'm a frequent SO user, so if you stumble across this and would like to know more, feel free to message me.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly build selection lists / radio buttons / check boxes based on  query - im not sure if this is exactly what you want to do ?

See http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice and the `query` parameter - I use this a lot and it works fine.

To build a whole form dynamically is going to be difficult IMO - I think you need to define at least some rules so that you can display / hide certain form elements.

Comment: I've pasted what I did here: http://pastebin.com/NrJeADAk

If you have any ideas on improving that or are just curious, take a look! It works well, but... Seeing as it's a strange thing to do, solutions for handling output are also strange to say the least. It has been a weird project.

For what it's worth, Symfony 2 has a built in solution for this and it looks stellar. I can't wait to migrate this project to that.